# Ruby - How to Merge a Hash into a method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this method

```
def method1
 {
  headers: { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }
 }
end
```

and this another method for merge a another key and value into this method1 hash, so

```
def merge_hash
  method1.merge!(body: { params: 123 }
end
```

so when i call method1 again i expect he returns a marged body and my questions is why not this happens or how i can do it?

Comment: It would be extremely confusing / bad practice to mutate a method response in this way. I can't give concrete advice without seeing more context than these two methods in isolation, but in general you should only mutate *variables*.

Comment: @MatheusLima : You basically wants to have a parameterless method, which returns something different, every time it is called, based on what happened to it before. Hence you want a method which holds some **state**. This is not forbidden, but I hope you know what you are going to do here. The trivial solution to achieve the effect:  Since your method lives in some class, you could use an instance variable to record the information needed for your operation.

Comment: Note that `method1.object_id #=> 70130617670800; method1.object_id #=> 70130617701620; method1.object_id #=> 70130621059620`. Do you see the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Each time you call `method1` it returns a new object:

```
> method1.object_id
=> 47220476550040 
> method1.object_id
=> 47220476543700
```

To achieve what you want you can memorize it after the first call:

```
def method1
  @method1 ||= {
    headers: { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }
  }
end

> method1.object_id
=> 47220477154400 
> method1.object_id
=> 47220477154400
```

I suggest to not mutate a hash this way because it can lead to bugs.

Comment: What you suggest to do in this case? because i need "concat" a new key and value to a existing hash when necessary, a body with params in this case is optional

Comment: It depends on your app. I'd create a variable to store all concatenated hashes, `my_hash = method1.merge(body: { params: 123 })`.

Comment: As @Tom Lord mentioned in his comment to the question. It's hard to advise you without a context.

Answer (score 0):

Of course `method1`'s return value does not change, because you haven't changed the method itself.

You can use the old and evil technique called **alias method chain**.

```
# Define a new method `method1_without_body`
# whose implementation is exactly the same
# as `method1` at this moment.
alias method1_without_body method1

# Define a new method that calls `method1_without_body`.
# Make sure that it does NOT call `method1`,
# or you'll get a stack overflow.
def method1_with_body
  method1_without_body.merge!(body: { params: 123 })
end

# Define a new method `method1`
# whose implementation is exactly the same
# as `method1_with_body`.
# This method shadows the previous implementation of `method1`.
alias method1 method1_with_body
```

or if you are using Rails < 5, then just

```
def method1_with_body
  method1_without_body.merge!(body: { params: 123 })
end

alias_method_chain :method1, :body
```

then when you call `method1`, it returns the hash with both headers and body.

By the way, this technique was deprecated since Rails 5 and was totally removed later (I forgot in which minor version).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this comes close to what you look at:

```
class MyClass

    attr_reader :method1

    def initialize
      @method1 = {  headers: { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' } }
    end

    def merge_hash
      @method1.merge!(body: { params: 123 }
    end

end
```

Hence, if you have a

```
o = MyClass.new
```

the first `o.method1` will return the initial hash, but after a

```
o.merge_hash
```

an `o.method1` will return the modified hash.